# ASP.NET Core: How would I go about binding data from user claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model-binding

I have a simple ASP.NET Core http API, and there are an awful lot of controller actions that all start like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete()
    {
        if (!User.Claims.TryGetClaim("merchant_id", out long merchantId))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        /* Real code using merchantId */
    }
```

I would like to reduce the duplication of the claims check each time, but I'm unsure how to go about it. I've got the code about as small as I can using just extension methods, but I'd like to get it smaller still, something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete([FromClaims] long merchantId)
{
    /* Real code using merchantId */
}
```

But I've been reading the docs on ASP.NET core middleware and I don't know what I have to implement to make this happen.

The built-in `FromBody` attribute inherits from `IBindingSourceMetadata`, which defines a `BindingSource` property. However, I can't find any resources online about how one might implement their own binding source to get items from the user claims.

Comment: I think a middleware could solve your problem

Comment: @dcg Umm, I know. That's what my question is.

Comment: Do you actually want binding, or do you just want an easy way to retrieve the merchant id? If you want something you can inject into services and such, I can share some code I used for something similar.

Comment: If you add the middleware you would still have to check in every action method. Roles are also claims, so you might be able to make a custom policy and add [Authorize(Policy = "CustomPolicy")] controller wide. OR override  'OnActionExecuting' in the controller to do the check for controller wide

Comment: I suppose I don't actually need binding, just an easy way of both requiring and getting the merchant ID

Answer (score 3):

You can use policy base authorization with attributes.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("ShouldHaveMerchantId", policy => 
              policy.RequireClaim("merchant_id"));
    });
    ...
}
```

And on your action methods use Authorize attribute with your policy name.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ShouldHaveMerchantId")]
public async Task<IActionResult> YourActionMethod()
{
    //Your logic
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best imo, only thing is now you would still have to parse it in every action method

Comment: As @Marcel said, this elegantly solves half the question. I still need a way of getting the content of this claim in every action method.

Comment: You will have to do an combination of the two

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which version the question is about, but at least in ASP.NET Core 6 and 7 you can create a custom value provider and an attribute like this:

### ClaimsValueProvider.cs

```
public class ClaimsValueProvider : BindingSourceValueProvider
{
    private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _principal;

    public ClaimsValueProvider(BindingSource bindingSource, ClaimsPrincipal principal) : base(bindingSource)
    {
        _principal = principal;
    }

    public override bool ContainsPrefix(String prefix)
    {
        return _principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == prefix);
    }

    public override ValueProviderResult GetValue(String key)
    {
        var claims = _principal.FindAll(key).Select(claim => claim.Value).ToArray();

        return claims.Any()
            ? new ValueProviderResult(claims, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            : ValueProviderResult.None;
    }
}
```

### ClaimsValueProviderFactory.cs

```
public class ClaimsValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory
{
    public Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        context.ValueProviders.Add(new ClaimsValueProvider(ClaimsBindingSource.BindingSource, context.ActionContext.HttpContext.User));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

### FromClaimAttribute.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FromClaimAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata, IModelNameProvider
{
    public FromClaimAttribute()
    {
    }

    public FromClaimAttribute(String claimType)
    {
        Name = claimType;
    }

    public String? Name { get; }

    public BindingSource BindingSource => ClaimsBindingSource.BindingSource;
}
```

### ClaimsBindingSource.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

public class ClaimsBindingSource : BindingSource
{
    private ClaimsBindingSource() : base("Claims", "Claims", false, true)
    {
    }

    public static ClaimsBindingSource BindingSource => new();
}
```

You have to add the ClaimsValueProviderFactory to you configuration like this:

### Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new ClaimsValueProviderFactory()))
```

If you also want to remove it from OpenAPI and Swagger, you can create this filter:

### FromClaimOpenApiParameterRemover.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

public class FromClaimOpenApiParameterRemover : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation? operation, OperationFilterContext? context)
    {
        if (operation == null || context?.ApiDescription?.ParameterDescriptions == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var parametersToHide = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions
            .Where(ParameterHasIgnoreAttribute)
            .Join(operation.Parameters, x => x.Name, y => y.Name, (_, y) => y)
            .ToList();

        if (!parametersToHide.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var parameter in parametersToHide)
        {
            operation.Parameters.Remove(parameter);
        }
    }

    private static bool ParameterHasIgnoreAttribute(ApiParameterDescription parameterDescription)
    {
        if (parameterDescription.ModelMetadata is not DefaultModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var attributes = metadata.Attributes.Attributes
            .Union(metadata.Attributes.ParameterAttributes ?? new List<Object>())
            .Union(metadata.Attributes.PropertyAttributes ?? new List<Object>());

        return attributes.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FromClaimAttribute));
    }
}
```

Add it to the Swagger generation like this:

### Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<FromClaimOpenApiParameterRemover>();
});
```

Comment: Nice and thorough answer. I think it's worth mentioning that this doesn't work for minimal APIs, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a middleware like this

```
public class MyMiddleware 
{
   private readonly RequestDelegate next;

   public MyMiddleware (RequestDelegate next)
   {
        this.next = next;
   }

   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext ctx) 
   {
       // Your check here, something like
       if (!ctx.User.Claims.TryGetClaim("merchant_id", out long merchantId))
       {
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
       }
       else
       {
            await next.Invoke(ctx);
       }

   }
}
```

and then register it like

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```

Comment: What if this should only apply to certain controller actions?

Comment: You have access to the entire `HttpContext` object, so you could do some filtering first

Comment: I think it'd be better to use a custom `AuthorizationHandler` in that case. Then you can decorate the necessary controller actions with an attribute rather than filtering in the middleware.

Comment: I suggestd the middleware 'cause the OP said a lot of actions started the same way.

Comment: You're not wrong if this is the norm for his application. I'm only assuming (I know, not a great idea haha) that "a lot of actions start the same way" but also "a lot of actions don't (or won't) start the same way."

Comment: Haha, I think in this case a custom policy is the way to go.